# limits of equal portions of a list with last portion getting all excess

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, divide

I'm looking for the best way to divide a given list for example list with 200 numbers.
I'd like to divide it into 3 parts, so I know there is a remainder for example.
This is what I came with, I'm sure there is better way:

```
int divider = 3;
int lastElements = this.mylist.size() % divider;
int listpart = this.mylist.size() / divider;
int listpartStart = 0;
int listpartEnd = listpart-1;
for(int i=0;i<divider;i++) {
  if(i==divider-1) {
      listpartEnd+=lastElements;
  }
   
  listpartEnd;
  listpartStart;

   
  someHandlingFunction(listpartStart,listpartEnd);
     
  listpartEnd+=listpart;
  listpartStart+=listpart;
}
```

Comment: This is highly unclear. Do you just want to calculate where the parts begin and end (e.g. [0,65], [66,131], [132,199]), or do you want to copy the elements to other containers, or what?

Comment: Please fix spelling, starting with `I'm` and all those small *i*s (look up *remainder* & don't forget the title). What *is* `this.mylist`? Do you use any specific language for coding?

Comment: Beta,Thanks, i want only the indexs, not the elements 
@greybeard i prefer java but any language will do if not using spacial unique API

Comment: Do the calls to `someHandlingFunction()` need to be in order of increasing parameter values? Please select a language family, at least: the mechanisms available in Prolog, Simula, PostScript, Python, … differ widely.

Comment: hey greybeard , its java the function someHandlingFunction sending the range 
for example : 0-100 , 100-200  ,200-300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to coming up with a concise implementation of this requirement is to recognize that the final part, the one that should get the excess, is a special case. So, loop `divisor-1` times and then handle the final part separately at the end.

```
void split(int size, int divider)
{
    int part = size / divider;
    for(int i=1; i<divider; i++)
    {
        someHandlingFunction((i-1)*part, (i*part)-1);
    }
    someHandlingFunction((divider-1)*part, size-1);
}

void someHandlingFunction(int start, int end) 
{
    System.out.println(start + " - " + end);
}
```

Note - you may want to add a check for the case where `size < divider` and handle it appropriately.

Test:

```
split(200, 3);
```

Output:

```
0 - 65
66 - 131
132 - 199
```